# Superimpose two shapefiles in R

Tags: r, shapefile, merge, sf

I have two shapefiles, one for provinces:

```
library(sf)

library(ggplot2)

prv_shp <- read_sf("decoupage/Provinces_2015.shp")

prv_shp |> ggplot() + geom_sf() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

and one for regions:

```
rgn_shp <- read_sf("decoupage/Regions_2015.shp")

rgn_shp |> ggplot() + geom_sf() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Knowing that provinces are subdivisions of regions (the borders of a region's provinces grouped together are the same as the borders of the said region), how can I superpose both shapefiles in such a way as to make them look like the answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497182/ggplot-create-a-border-overlay-on-top-of-map)?

The data looks like this:

```
> str(rgn_shp)
sf [12 × 4] (S3: sf/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ OBJECTID  : int [1:12] 1 4 5 6 8 9 13 17 19 20 ...
 $ Shape_Leng: num [1:12] 11.17 11.61 9.09 9.43 13.01 ...
 $ Shape_Area: num [1:12] 4.26 3.71 1.94 1.82 3.85 ...
 $ geometry  :sfc_POLYGON of length 12; first list element: List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:5203, 1:2] -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 ...
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "XY" "POLYGON" "sfg"
 - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
 - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "OBJECTID" "Shape_Leng" "Shape_Area"
> str(prv_shp)
sf [75 × 22] (S3: sf/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ OBJECTID_1: int [1:75] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ NAME      : chr [1:75] "Assa Zag" "Guelmim" "Tan Tan" "Tata" ...
 $ pop_maroca: num [1:75] 44120 187613 1060302 117809 596891 ...
 $ pop_etrang: num [1:75] 4 195 5299 32 3708 ...
 $ pop_total_: num [1:75] 44124 187808 1065601 117841 600599 ...
 $ menages_14: num [1:75] 44124 187808 1065601 117841 600599 ...
 $ class_pop : int [1:75] 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 ...
 $ SRF       : num [1:75] 22741 11002 9498 26216 2430 ...
 $ DENSITE_14: num [1:75] 1.94 17.07 112.19 4.5 247.19 ...
 $ RuleID    : int [1:75] 1 2 5 1 5 4 5 3 5 2 ...
 $ Shape_Leng: num [1:75] 6.72 6.47 4.16 10.61 2.93 ...
 $ Shape_Area: num [1:75] 2.088 1.018 0.872 2.442 0.229 ...
 $ menage_urb: num [1:75] 3931 30332 253831 7992 124107 ...
 $ pop_urb   : num [1:75] 27333 139246 1005041 40820 508155 ...
 $ etrange_ur: num [1:75] 2 144 5259 24 3631 ...
 $ marocain_u: num [1:75] 27331 139102 999782 40796 504524 ...
 $ menage_rur: num [1:75] 1277 9882 12907 14367 19645 ...
 $ pop_rur   : num [1:75] 16791 48562 60560 77021 92444 ...
 $ etranger_r: num [1:75] 2 51 40 8 77 128 9 57 191 91 ...
 $ marocain_r: num [1:75] 16789 48511 60520 77013 92367 ...
 $ prcnt_urb : num [1:75] 61.9 74.1 94.3 34.6 84.6 ...
 $ geometry  :sfc_POLYGON of length 75; first list element: List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:348, 1:2] -8.67 -8.74 -8.76 -8.79 -8.8 ...
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "XY" "POLYGON" "sfg"
 - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
 - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:21] "OBJECTID_1" "NAME" "pop_maroca" "pop_etrang" ...
```

**EDIT**

I recreated the following data set in order to combine both `province` and `region` in a single place:

```
> str(map_4)
Classes ‘sf’ and 'data.frame':  72 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ PROV    : chr  "Agadir-Ida-Ou-Tanane" "Al Haouz" "Al Hoceïma" "Azilal" ...
 $ MEPI    : num  4.75 12.56 8.72 4.78 5.74 ...
 $ H       : num  9.81 25.42 16.33 9.56 11.21 ...
 $ reg     : chr  "Souss-Massa" "Marrakech-Safi" "Tanger-Tétouan-Al Hoceïma" "Béni Mellal-Khénifra" ...
 $ geometry:sfc_POLYGON of length 72; first list element: List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:2257, 1:2] -9.5 -9.5 -9.5 -9.5 -9.5 ...
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "XY" "POLYGON" "sfg"
 - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
 - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "PROV" "MEPI" "H" "reg"
```

and then proceeded to create the the superimposed map as follows:

```
map_4 |> ggplot() +
  geom_sf(colour = "gray50") +
  geom_sf(fill = "transparent", color = "red", lwd = 1, data = . %>% group_by(reg) %>% summarise()) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Greys", trans = "reverse") +
  theme_void() +
  coord_sf(ndiscr = F)
```

and it gave me this map:

[image]

I was expecting the red lines to be the same as the `regions` map, which is not the case. So, replicating the answer in the link above did not solve the problem.

Comment: I am a bit confused, how do the answers to the linked question not answer your question?

Comment: It doesn't. The answer in the link has the `regions` and `provinces` in one dataset. I have them in separate datasets.

Comment: Did you already check `?sf::st_join`?

Comment: @dimfalk I saw it being used here: https://jayrobwilliams.com/posts/2021/05/geom-sf-facet . Can it be used to solve this problem? Do you know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I mock your data

```r
rgn_shp <- giscoR::gisco_get_nuts(country = "ITA", nuts_level = 2)
prv_shp <- giscoR::gisco_get_nuts(country = "ITA", nuts_level = 3)
```

Now just plot the shapefiles in the desired order and manipulate the layers accordingly. Pay attention to `fill = NA` that would plot only the borders:

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(rgn_shp) +
  # Layer for background
  # Use your var instead of NUTS_NAME
  geom_sf(data = rgn_shp, aes(fill = NUTS_NAME), show.legend = FALSE) +
  # Layer for inner lines
  geom_sf(data = prv_shp, fill = NA) +
  # Layer for outer lines
  geom_sf(data = rgn_shp, fill = NA, linewidth = 0.4, color = "black")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `giscoR` - I almost write `discoR`, which would certainly make a great package name! Was wondering where to get admin areas to create a reproducible example at first... :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Before writing an excessive comment, I might try to post and answer as well. Since you did not provide data to work with and the popular `nc` dataset does not seem to contain several administrative levels, I'll try to demonstrate my current approach using the `vg250` administrative boundaries of Germany dataset:

```r
# devtools::install_github("dimfalk/vg250")
library(vg250)

# sneak peek preview; dataset containing 11.123 features
vg250 <- vg250[, c("GEM", "KRS")]
vg250
#> Simple feature collection with 11123 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 5.86625 ymin: 47.27012 xmax: 15.04182 ymax: 55.05878
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> First 10 features:
#>                    GEM          KRS                           geom
#> 1            Flensburg    Flensburg MULTIPOLYGON (((9.412137 54...
#> 2                 Kiel         Kiel MULTIPOLYGON (((10.16852 54...
#> 3               Lübeck       Lübeck MULTIPOLYGON (((10.87526 53...
#> 4           Neumünster   Neumünster MULTIPOLYGON (((9.991971 54...
#> 5          Brunsbüttel Dithmarschen MULTIPOLYGON (((9.166074 53...
#> 6                Heide Dithmarschen MULTIPOLYGON (((9.121658 54...
#> 7              Averlak Dithmarschen MULTIPOLYGON (((9.212443 53...
#> 8             Brickeln Dithmarschen MULTIPOLYGON (((9.255627 54...
#> 9             Buchholz Dithmarschen MULTIPOLYGON (((9.182763 53...
#> 10 Burg (Dithmarschen) Dithmarschen MULTIPOLYGON (((9.277097 54...

# test approach using a subset, 120 objects of type GEM forming 1 object of type KRS in this case
dithm_gem <- dplyr::filter(vg250, KRS == "Dithmarschen")
dithm_gem
#> Simple feature collection with 120 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 8.678873 ymin: 53.87751 xmax: 9.444421 ymax: 54.37899
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> First 10 features:
#>                    GEM          KRS                           geom
#> 1          Brunsbüttel Dithmarschen MULTIPOLYGON (((9.166074 53...
#> 2                Heide Dithmarschen MULTIPOLYGON (((9.121658 54...
#> 3              Averlak Dithmarschen MULTIPOLYGON (((9.212443 53...
#> 4             Brickeln Dithmarschen MULTIPOLYGON (((9.255627 54...
#> 5             Buchholz Dithmarschen MULTIPOLYGON (((9.182763 53...
#> 6  Burg (Dithmarschen) Dithmarschen MULTIPOLYGON (((9.277097 54...
#> 7               Dingen Dithmarschen MULTIPOLYGON (((9.171598 53...
#> 8              Eddelak Dithmarschen MULTIPOLYGON (((9.173234 53...
#> 9             Eggstedt Dithmarschen MULTIPOLYGON (((9.255236 54...
#> 10            Frestedt Dithmarschen MULTIPOLYGON (((9.16114 54....

sf::st_geometry(dithm_gem) |> plot()
```

[image]

```r
# group by KRS and summarize making use of `st_union()`
dithm_krs <- dplyr::group_by(dithm_gem, KRS) |> dplyr::summarize(geom = sf::st_union(geom)) 

sf::st_geometry(dithm_krs) |> plot()
```

[image]

```r
# transfer this approach to the full dataset resulting in 378 features
vg250_krs <- dplyr::group_by(vg250, KRS) |> dplyr::summarize(geom = sf::st_union(geom)) 
vg250_krs
#> Simple feature collection with 378 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: GEOMETRY
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 5.86625 ymin: 47.27012 xmax: 15.04182 ymax: 55.05878
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 378 × 2
#>    KRS                                                                      geom
#>    <chr>                                                           <POLYGON [°]>
#>  1 Ahrweiler                 ((7.298057 50.45906, 7.297959 50.45947, 7.29822 50…
#>  2 Aichach-Friedberg         ((10.93851 48.26735, 10.93773 48.26747, 10.93719 4…
#>  3 Alb-Donau-Kreis           ((9.863978 48.27067, 9.865263 48.27124, 9.866308 4…
#>  4 Altenburger Land          ((12.34613 51.09752, 12.34588 51.09819, 12.3431 51…
#>  5 Altenkirchen (Westerwald) ((7.720162 50.73112, 7.722795 50.73051, 7.723539 5…
#>  6 Altmarkkreis Salzwedel    ((10.89972 52.85516, 10.8994 52.85542, 10.89889 52…
#>  7 Altötting                 ((12.59549 48.22767, 12.59365 48.22735, 12.59266 4…
#>  8 Alzey-Worms               ((8.19531 49.82338, 8.195132 49.8236, 8.194128 49.…
#>  9 Amberg                    ((11.87629 49.4952, 11.87437 49.49706, 11.87397 49…
#> 10 Amberg-Sulzbach           ((11.94516 49.27867, 11.94582 49.27978, 11.9462 49…
#> # ℹ 368 more rows
```

As soon as your features have region attributes for your province geometries, this can easily be solved. In order to achieve this, as noted in the comments, make use of `sf::st_join()`. An example referring to the referenced `vg250` dataset above is given in [/data-raw/](https://github.com/dimfalk/vg250/blob/740fb6c6509d5a0296dd07294cd3aea2ca07fb31/data-raw/vg250.R#L30) of the repo.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.